# Not able to manipulate date on Unix shell script (date: illegal option -- d)

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I have a requirement to add 10 days to current date and assign it to a variable. But I am getting error:

```
date: illegal option -- d
```

This is what I tried:

```
$> NEW_expration_DATE=$(date -d "+10 days")
```

Result:

```
date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. Which OS is this? OSX/Linux? When you do `man date`, which command line flags do you have available?

Answer (score 13):

Try this: 
NEW_expration_DATE=$(gdate -d "+10 days")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a **POSIX shell**, and that there is **no way** to do simple date arithmetic in here.

I found a guy who explains it and who coded something to substract dates. You may be able to adapt it for your case: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7220/162444

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the system with "unmane -a" and do a fine search, for example in AIX can use to get yesterday:

```
YESTERDAY=`TZ=aaa24 date +%Y%m%d`
```